# Android Warning: Native component for "RCTMap" does not exist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I created a react native project and I am trying to use a map for Android. I am using airbnb react-native-maps package, as suggested in the Facebook react native page. 
I followed the instructions, added my google api key in the manifest. In iOS it works perfectly, however on Android it gives me a warning and it does not show me the map: "Warning: Native component for 'RCTMap' does not exist".
 Here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableHighlight, MapView } from 'react-native';
import Header from '../common/header';
import HomeStyleSheet from '../../style/home/homeStyleSheet';

export default class Results extends Component{

  //...


  render(){

    return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        <Header headerText='RESULTS'>
        </Header>
          <MapView
            style={{ height: 300, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0 }}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            region={{
              latitude: 43.683470,
              longitude: -79.318006,
              latitudeDelta: 0.03,
              longitudeDelta:0.03
            }}/>
        <View style={{ height: 5, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting the warning? I searched similar problems here but almost everyone said to use airbnb react-native-maps (and l did). Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can close the question. Between all the changes I did to make it work,I didn't realize I was importing MapView from 'react-native' instead of 'react-native-maps'. Fixed it:

```js
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
```

Comment: Can you help me in one issue, which I think you have solved as per your question. Check the below link and check if you can help !!!!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914735/native-component-for-airmap-does-not-exist