# Native component for "AIRMap" does not exist

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

```
react-native: 0.53.3
react-native-maps@0.20.1
```

I'm trying to use [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps) and I keep getting this error. This is in a fresh project:

```
react-native init maps
cd maps/
npm install --save react-native-maps
react-native run-ios
```

And in `App.js` I've added this:

```
...
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <MapView
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      }}
    />
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This seems to be the bare minimum to get this running, but my iOS simulator is complaining about "AIRMap".

[image]

Comment: Cocoapods installation was successful?

Comment: @TimH Please forgive my ignorance, I'm new to react and mobile development. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: did you follow these instructions: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md ?

Comment: @TimH I tried to, but I don't have a `ios/Podfile`. I thought that might something to do with the build process which I was gonna ignore for now.

Comment: That's the problem. First install CocoaPods on your Mac and then create a Podfile for your app.

Comment: @TimH Ah, so I am supposed to make the file? Do you know what they mean by `_YOUR_PROJECT_TARGET_`? Do I make this up?

Comment: _YOUR_PROJECT_TARGET_ is basically your app name. E.g. your app's name is "TestApp" then you will have different targets inside your Podfile. 
But you need to include the lines from the instructions only inside your 'TestApp' target.

Comment: but actually the target will be auto generated by cocoapods. You just need to include the lines from the installation guide.

Comment: @TimH I'm at a white screen, but it seems like I've resolved the error. Thanks.

Comment: @TimH - And what about the android?? How to solve this for android....

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the same result after following the instructions and the solution at the end was really simple.

I went to Xcode -> Clean -> Build.

> There I saw that I had 2 errors in my code:

1. Expected ';' after module name (@import GoogleMaps)
2. Use of undeclared identifier ([GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:@"MY_KEY"];)

So, I added  ';' and deleted the line GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:@"MY_KEY"];

After that I executed again **'npm run ios'** and all worked like a charm!

There are other solutions here:

1. https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1798
2. https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/2064